# How can a shortcode can take the place of the featured image in a post?

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails

When there is a specific shortcode in a post (example `[sc]anything[/sc]`), I want to hide the featured and take it's place. How can I do that?

I add this on my theme function

```
// TopWide Shortcode
function wpsite_topwide( $atts, $content = null ){
    return '<div class="topwide">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'topwide', 'wpsite_topwide' );

/** 
 * Find if content has topwide shortcode in it. 
 */ 
function wpsite_has_topwide_shortcode() { 
    global $post; 

    if ( ! is_single() ) 
        return; 

    if ( false === strpos( $post->post_content, '[topwide' ) ) 
        return false; 

    return true; 
}
```

and this on  single post

```
<?php
if (wpsite_has_topwide_shortcode() && has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    echo '<div class="topwide">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' ) . '</div>'; 
} 
?>
```

But doesn't takes the place of the featured image in the post...

Comment: I think the shortcode detection part has a solution here, try to dig in the archives

Comment: @brasofilo I tried, but I think something I have done wrong, check plz if you can help me

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are simply not translating your logic into code:

- if it has shortcode, do this,
- if not has shortcode but has thumbnail, do that,
- otherwise, do something else.

```
if ( wpsite_has_topwide_shortcode() ) { 
    echo 'shortcode';
} elseif( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' );
} else {
    echo 'Hello World';
}
```

Comment: this: <?php
if ( wpsite_has_topwide_shortcode() ) { 
    get_shortcode(); 
} elseif( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
  get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'full' )
} 
?> ?

Comment: Did you try it? :) - But, yes, this is it.

Comment: yes, i get this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/xx/public_html/wp-content/themes/xxxx/content-single.php on line 71

Comment: You have a missing semi-colon `;` in `get_the_post_thumb`. A good IDE would have shown that, eg, NetBeans.

Comment: now i get unexpected ';'  :/

Comment: Go commenting lines `//` and/or eliminating code blocks until you nail the error.

Comment: in line 71 is the above code

Comment: Updated the Answer. I tested it and it's working ok. Your error must be somewhere else. Follow the advice of my last comment.

Comment: I tried many ways and I didn't get an error, but, it didn't take the shortcode from the content and put it in the place of the featured image. No matter what I tried, the only thing it did was to show blank the place of the featured image, and whatever the shortcode had in it, it remained in the content.

Comment: Ok! I did it but, under the display of the short code it shows me the photo. :/